# Replace text with data & matched group contents

Tags: java, regex

I don't believe I saw this when searching (believe me, I spent a good amount of time searching for this) for a solution to this so here goes.

Goal:
Match regex in a string and replace it with something that contains the matched value.

Regex used currently:

```
\b(Connor|charries96|Foo|Bar)\b
```

*For the record I suck at regex incase this isn't the best way to do it.*

My current code (and several other methods I tried) can only replace the text with the first match it encounters if there are multiple matches.

```
private Pattern regexFromList(List<String> input) {
    if(input.size() < 1) {
        return "";
    }

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("\\b");
    builder.append("(");
    for(String s : input) {
        builder.append(s);
        if(!s.equals(input.get(input.size() - 1)))
        {
            builder.append("|");
        }
    }
    builder.append(")");
    builder.append("\\b");

    return Pattern.compile(builder.toString(), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
}
```

Example input:

```
charries96's name is Connor.
```

Example result using TEST as the data to prepend the match with

```
TESTcharries96's name is TESTcharries96.
```

Desired result using example input:

```
TESTcharries96's name is TESTConnor.
```

Here is my current code for replacing the text:

```
if(highlight) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher match = pattern.matcher(event.getMessage());
    String string = event.getMessage();

    if (match.find()) {
        string = match.replaceAll("TEST" + match.group());
        // I do realise I'm using #replaceAll but that's mainly given it gives me the same result as other methods so why not just cut to the chase.
    }
    builder.append(string);
    return builder.toString();
 }
```

**EDIT:**
Working example of desired result on [RegExr](http://regexr.com/39p7u)

Comment: Use `replaceAll("TEST$1")` alone to achieve what you want. Throw away the `find()`, which is a lower level function for more fine grained control (which needs to be used with appendReplacement and appendTail).

Comment: @nhahtdh can't believe it was that simple, thankyou! Mind posting it as an answer so I can mark is as that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

- You are taking the user input as is and build the regex:

  ```
  builder.append(s);
  ```

  If there are special character in the user input, it might be recognized as meta character and cause unexpected behavior.

  Always use [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) if you want to match a string as it is passed in.

  ```
  builder.append(Pattern.quote(s));
  ```
- [`Matcher.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29) is a high level function which **resets** the Matcher (start the match all over again), and search for all the matches and perform the replacement. In your case, it can be as simple as:

  ```
  String result = match.replaceAll("TEST$1");
  ```

  The `StringBuilder` should be thrown away along with the if statement.
- `Matcher.find`, `Matcher.group` are lower level functions for fine grain control on what you want to do with a match.

  When you perform replacement, you need to build the result with `Matcher.appendReplacement` and `Matcher.appendTail`.

  A while loop (instead of if statement) should be used with `Matcher.find` to search for and perform replacement for all matched.